# Key Description in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using SQL Server and Entity Framework 6.2.0.  I've got the unique key in the image below in SQL server, notice the highlighted 'Description' field.  When this key is violated, Entity Framework throws an UpdateException.  Is there anyway to get this 'Description' field from that exception?

[image: Unique Key Description Sql Server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve them from the catalog on demand or on startup with a query like:

```
select k.name, cast(p.value as nvarchar(500)) value
from sys.extended_properties p
join sys.key_constraints k
  on p.major_id = k.object_id
 and p.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
 and minor_id = 0
where p.name = 'MS_Description'
```

But matching the key constraints to the error messages is up to you.

Comment: This gets the job done.  I pull out the constraint name from the exception message with this:                                                                                                        Regex regex = new Regex("^Violation of (?<KeyType>.*?) constraint '(?<ConstraintName>[^']*)'\\.[^']*'(?<ObjectName>[^']*)'[^(]*\\((?<KeyValue>[^)]*)\\)");
            Match match = regex.Match(message);
            string name = null;
            if (match != null && match.Groups["ConstraintName"] != null)
            {
                name = match.Groups["ConstraintName"].Value;
            }